# AngularJS : return object to be used again in factory

Tags: angularjs, promise, factory

I'm trying to create a wrapper / factory around the [cordova media plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media), which requires you to create a new Media object, and then use it again to pause, stop, play, etc it.

The factory + [link to actual code](https://github.com/driftyco/ng-cordova/blob/master/src/plugins/media.js):

```
.factory('$cordovaMedia', ['$q', function ($q) {

return {
  newMedia: function (src) {
    var q = $q.defer();
    var mediaStatus = null;

    var media = new Media(src,
      function (success) {
        q.resolve(success);
      }, function (error) {
        q.reject(error);
      }, function (status) {
        mediaStatus = status;
      });

    return {
      media: media,
      mediaStatus: mediaStatus,
      promise: q.promise
    }
  },


  play: function (source) {
    return source.play();
  },

  stop: function (source) {
    return source.play();
  }
  }]);
```

Example usage of how the factory works with this implementation:

```
var media = $cordovaMedia.newMedia('some/src.mp3').media

$cordovaMedia.play(media);
$cordovaMedia.stop(media);
```

As you can see I'm creating a new `Media` object, and assigning it to a variable and using it again through the factory.

I'm wondering if there is a better way of doing this? Mainly what is the best way in AngularJS to create an object in a factory, which must be used again, through the same factory?

Comment: In factory can create a cache object using  source url as object keys. If the media already exists in cache, resolve with what is in cache, otherwise create a new one, add to cache and then resolve with the new media object

Comment: For asking about critique and best practices in existing code you might have better luck at codereview.stackexchange.com . Best practices questions are subjective and are often closed at StackOverflow.